# Trying to calculate consecutive operands with a basic HTML calculator for the Odin Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, calculator

I'm currently doing the calculator project on The Odin Project. This calculator does not require BEDMAS.  I've gotten to the point of being able to do calculations, as long as I only do two operands and a single operator.

For example, 2 + 2 + 2 will still return 4 instead of 6.

To fix this problem, I've tried to add an if statement at the beginning of the function that is activated whenever I use an operator button more than once ( +, -, * etc.), it attempted to check whether there was already an operator active, and if there was, performed a calculation when the operator was selected again. This solution didn't work, and I can't wrap my head around a way to tackle this problem.

I apologize in advance for the messy code, but if someone can point me in the right direction or determine whether I should rework my calculator entirely, I would really appreciate it.

Code: https://codepen.io/jordan-ayotte/pen/MWjgMrQ
javascript:

```
 function multiply (x, y) {
 return x * y;
 }
 function add (x, y) {
 return x + y;
 }
 function subtract (x, y) {
 return  x - y;
 }
 function divide (x , y) {
 return x / y;
 }

const numberButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("numberButtons");
const operatorButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("operatorButtons");
const equalsButton = document.getElementById("=");
const clearButton = document.getElementById("AC");
let calcDisplay = document.querySelector("#calculatorDisplay")
let currentOperand = [];
let previousOperand = [];
let currentOperator;
let operandCounter;

for ( i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++) {
numberButtons[i].addEventListener("click", populateDisplay)
}

for ( j = 0; j < operatorButtons.length; j++) {
operatorButtons[j].addEventListener("click", storeFirstOperand)
}

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
calcDisplay.innerText = '';
currentOperand = '';
})

equalsButton.addEventListener("click", function calculate () {
if (currentOperator == '+') {
let result = parseInt(add(parseInt(currentOperand), parseInt(calcDisplay.innerText)))
console.log(result)
calcDisplay.innerText = result
previousOperand = result
currentOperand = result;
}

if (currentOperator == '-') { let result = parseInt(subtract(parseInt(currentOperand), 
parseInt(calcDisplay.innerText)))
console.log(result)
calcDisplay.innerText = result 
previousOperand = result
currentOperand = result;                           
}
if (currentOperator == '*') { let result = parseInt(multiply(parseInt(currentOperand), 
parseInt(calcDisplay.innerText)))
console.log(result)
calcDisplay.innerText = result 
previousOperand = result 
currentOperand = result;                             
}
if (currentOperator == '/') { let result = parseInt(divide(parseInt(currentOperand), 
parseInt(calcDisplay.innerText)))
console.log(result)
calcDisplay.innerText = result
previousOperand = result   
currentOperand = result;                              
}

});


function storeFirstOperand (event) { 
if (currentOperand && currentOperator) { if (currentOperator = '+') {
let result = currentOperand + calcDisplay.innerText;
calcDisplay.innerText = result;
}
 
}
let operator = event.target.id;
currentOperator = operator
if (operandCounter == 1) {
console.log("hello")
}
if (currentOperand = false) { function storeLastOperand () {
previousOperand = currentOperand;
console.log(currentOperand)
calcDisplay.innerText = ''
console.log('hello')
}} else if (currentOperand == '') {

currentOperand += parseFloat(calcDisplay.innerText)
calcDisplay.innerText = ''
console.log(currentOperand)
operandCounter ++;
}}


function populateDisplay(currentNumberValue) {

let passedValue= event.target.id;
calcDisplay.innerText += passedValue
console.log(parseInt(calcDisplay.innerText))
}



console.log(calcDisplay.innerText)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, lets say you have a theoretical method `evaluate('1 + 1')` that returned `2`.  If you had `evaluate('1 + 1 + 1')`, that could also be the same as `evaluate('1') + evaluate('1 + 1')`, right?

Comment: Without the BEDMAS requirement, we just need to evaluate the sentence from left to right. The base case is that `evaluate(x) = x` where `x` is some number. Inductively, `evaluate(expr # x) = evaluate(expr) # evaluate(x)` where `#` is some binary operation and `expr` is an expression (`1 + 2 * 4 ...` etc). Notice how we make have to make our recursive calls in reverse.